# Bitwise operations in embedded C if button pressed on AVR circuit

Tags: arduino, avr, c, atmega, embedded

I am using ATmega32 AVR microcontroller. I am confused about bitwise operation in embedded C. I understand (AND, OR, XOR, NOT) logic gates very well, but there is something that I don't understand:

1. I understand this block of code:

   ```
   if ((PINB&(1<<PB0))==0x01) //if button pressed
   {
       //Do something
   }
   ```
2. But I don't understand why if I edited that to be:

   ```
    if (PINB &(1<<PB0))    //if button pressed
   {
      //Do something
   }
   ```

Does the same function...

In other words, what is the default value of `PINB` which made the two blocks of code have the same functionality?

Comment: The example number 1 will work only if PB0 equals 0.  Whereas example number 2 will work for any value of PB0.

Comment: @kkrambo Is not it that the default value of `PB0` is always 0 ?

Comment: How could we possibly know the default value of `PB0`? You haven't told us anything about it.

Comment: Maybe PB0 equals 0 and example 1 works.  Now suppose you add another button that is connected to PB1.  So you cut and paste your button code and change PB0 to PB1.  The pattern in example 1 will no longer work for your new button because PB1 is not equal to 0.  Don't follow the pattern in example 1.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson PB0 is defined 0 in one of the headers.

Comment: @Jeroen3 Thanks, the OP should have included more information about the headers and their development environment in the question.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, i think that you are missing the meaning of the question ... it appears that the OP is not aware of the numerical value of the booleans `true` and `false`

Comment: @ElliotAlderson @jsotola No,I am aware of  the numerical value of the booleans `true` and `false` . But in my question , I asked what is the default value of `PINB` , and I did NOT realize that its value is variable . *IT DEPENDS ON WHICH  INPUT OF THAT REGISTER IS*. That what made me confused !.
* * Thank you all  * *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example number 1 is not a good pattern to follow because it will work only if PB0 equals 0.  Example number 2 is a better pattern to follow because it will work for all values of PB0.  Example 1 can be edited to work for all values of PB0 like this:

```
if ((PINB & (1<<PB0)) == (1<<PB0)) //if button pressed
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first expression shows a common error in embedded programming. Note that the expression `PINB&(1<<PB0)` has two variables, `PINB` and `PB0`. Exxentially the result of this expression will be equal to `1 << PB0` if and only if bit number `PB0` in `PINB` is a 0. Note that the result can be equal to `0x1` **only** if the value of `PB0` is 0, so the entire conditional will **never** evaluate as true if `PB0` has any value other than 0.

The second example performs the same bit-wise AND operation, but it relies on the fact that a non-zero integer evaluates as a logical `true` in C. So, if the result of the expression is 0x20 we can infer that `PB0` equals 5 and that bit 5 in `PINB` is a 1.

Answer (score 0):

An if statement is true if the expression compares unequal to 0.

This means that as long as the and operation `PINB &(1<<PB0)` return a value above zero, it is true.
And the only way for the above expression to do so is when PB0 is 1 in the PINB register.

This means the equality operator `==0x01` would be redundant, and fault sensitive due to it requiring to have the correct bit in the parameter. If the parameter is mandatory in the style guide, use `(1<<PB0)` again.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. 
I want to know why  `PINB &(1<<PB0)` return a value above zero ? and whati is this value?

Comment: The `==0x01` is not redundant in these examples.  The `==0x01` is probably a mistake because the resulting conditional can only possibly test true if PB0 equals 0.  The `==0x01` conditional will not work correctly for any other values of PB0.

Comment: What does "when PB0 is set" mean? I think your explanation of how the conditional expression works is missing a lot of detail.

Comment: @AbdulrhmanAboghanima PB0 is defined as 0 in avr/io.h, and PINB is the PORT input register. You perform an & on it with a 1. (the 1 is left shifted 0 times, stays 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((PINB&(1<<PB0))==0x01)
```

Here we evaluate if the state of the bit with this register is set.
if it evaluates to hex 0x01 or 1 we proceed.

```
if (PINB &(1<<PB0))
```

here we have the same expression but we don't compare it.

Remember the if statements prototype:

```
if (test expression) 
{
    // statements to be executed if the test expression is true
}
```

now recall that logic 1 = true and logic 0 = false;

So if we simply write -

```
int x = 1;
if(x)
{
// do something.
}
```

The expression we want to evaluate (x) is true because its 1.

Comment: No, those two conditional statements **are not** exactly the same. If `PB0` has any non-zero value then the expression `(PINB&(1<<PB0))==0x01` will **never** evaluate to true.

Comment: I see thank you for clarifying @ElliotAlderson :)

Answer (score 0):

You said you understood logical operations very well so what is the question?

Why (x&1)==1 is equivalent to (x&1)!=0?

What are the possible outcomes of x&1?

1 and 0.  So you can either compare x&1 to 1 or not 0 if you want to test for the result being a 1.

Has nothing to do with embedded, it is just the C language.

kkrambo has a good point, although experience will show what bit is being isolated the code should have either simply anded with 1 or compared with the thing being anded (1<

```
if ((PINB&(1<<PB0))!=0)
```

For C boolean, false is defined as zero and true is not-zero

so if(z) will be false if z is 0 and true if z is not zero

if(x&1) will be true if x[0] is 1 and false if x[0] is 0.  So the if((x&1)!=0) is equivalent but reads better.

For some folks the defines/macros make life easier, for others (myself included) they make life much worse, very unreadable.  The logic isnt going to change so programming to the logic is fine, IMO you need to justify the abstraction. YMMV